# Фильтрация многовложенного массива js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

Как можно отфильтровать массив такого вида:

```js
[
  {
    id: 1,
    tasks: [
      {
        id: 11,
        title: "test1",
        category: [
          {
            id: 33,
            title: "Category 1"
          },
          {
            id: 44,
            title: "Category 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 12,
        title: "test2",
        category: [
          {
            id: 55,
            title: "Category 4"
          },
          {
            id: 66,
            title: "Category 7"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    tasks: [
      {
        id: 22,
        title: "test3",
        category: [
          {
            id: 333,
            title: "Category 1"
          },
          {
            id: 441,
            title: "Category 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 121,
        title: "test4",
        category: [
          {
            id: 553,
            title: "Category 14"
          },
          {
            id: 646,
            title: "Category 45"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Нужно возращать массив, например, по title и по category, категорий может быть несколько

Пример массива на выходе, если categories = [ 33, 44 ]:

```js
[
  {
    id: 1,
    tasks: [
      {
        id: 11,
        title: "test1",
        category: [
          {
            id: 33,
            title: "Category 1"
          },
          {
            id: 44,
            title: "Category 2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    tasks: [
      {
        id: 22,
        title: "test3",
        category: [
          {
            id: 33,
            title: "Category 1"
          },
          {
            id: 44,
            title: "Category 2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Понимаю, сложности в этом нету, но, когда я обращаюсь к массиву этих элементов через forEach и внутри хочу фильтровать tasks, то получаю undefined

Comment: приведи пример результата, который ты хочешь получить для приведенного примера

Comment: например, хочу получить основной объект, в котором есть tasks, фильтровтаь хочу по категориям

Comment: Добавь ожидаемый результат в сам вопрос.

Comment: @Grundy добавил!

Comment: Как у тебя из первого массива второй получился?

Comment: Вернули массив же

Comment: у тебя в test3 другие id у категорий стали

Comment: Были 334 и 441, а стали 33 и 44

Answer (score 0):

Решил вложенными фильтрами! Пример:

```js
const filteredArray = array.filter(el => {
  el.tasks = el.tasks.filter(el => {
    return el.id == 'task.607e78407477715c11107d01'
  })
  return el.tasks
})
```

Comment: добавь код не картинкой, а текстом. Данный подход плохой - потому что меняет исходный массив. Следовательно фильтровать ты можешь только один раз

Comment: как лучше тогда сделать? Я понимаю проблему то что я меняю исходный массив, как тогда избежать этого?

Comment: чтобы не менять исходный, нужно сделать копию